# Radio button second click makes uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, radio-button

If my radio button previously checked and i try to uncheck with second click i have to click once more. So it means if my radio button previously checked i got to clicked 2 times for unchecked but it should works with only 1 click . How can i fix it. Here is 2 codes they both have the same issue. I show both scripts here .Thanks For Helping!

```
 $(function(){
    $('input[name="rad"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

---

```
 $("input:radio").on("click", function (e) {
    var inp = $(this);
    if (inp.is(".clicked")) {
        inp.prop("checked", false).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
        $("input:radio[name='" + inp.prop("name") + "'].clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        inp.addClass("clicked");
    }
});
```

---

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio0" checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio1" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio2" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio4" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio3" />
```

---

and here is my html and jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fbyg1htz/

http://jsfiddle.net/7g684219/

Comment: What is the `data-waschecked` attribute for? Should a currently-checked `<input>` have `data-waschecked` set to `true`? Or should that only reflect an element that was checked previously once it's no longer checked?

Answer (score 0):

The input element which is selected by default (`checked="checked"`) should have the `waschecked` data attribute set to true because it's already checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio0" data-waschecked="true" checked="checked"/>
```

And the same for the second example. You should add `class="clicked"` to the element that is initially checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio0" class="clicked" checked="checked"/>
```

Updated fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fqLexbr/

http://jsfiddle.net/rmuh1sz3/

**Example with razor for your first script:**

```html
<input type="radio" id="status_active" value="true" asp-for="ActiveOrPassive"
       data-waschecked="@Model.OrderFilter.ActiveOrPassive.ToString().ToLower()" />
```

**and for your second script:**

```html
<input type="radio" id="status_active" value="true" asp-for="ActiveOrPassive"
       class="@(Model.OrderFilter.ActiveOrPassive ? "clicked" : null)" />
```

Comment: Yes this could be help but what if i dont know that radio button were clicked customer will click that i cant preclicked

Comment: Then remove `checked="checked"` and all radio buttons will be unchecked by default.

Comment: it's come from Model

Comment: Can you post the razor code then? Your question code doesn't have any model.

Comment: '<input type="radio" id="status_active" value="true" asp-for="OrderFilter.ActiveOrPassive">' it's a filter for my list on page. When user click active button and post it, it comes back to our view (page) with 'checked="checked"' for radio "status_active" right? but user has to click twice for uncheck the radio but i want is he click only once for uncheck

Comment: Check updated answer.